# jQuery Accordion tabs don't open using responsive tabs to Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI for information display on desktops in tabs and have so for some time. I have added [Responsive Tabs to Accordion](https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion) to show the same information in accordion tabs for tablets and smartphones as I am making the site responsive. The information is now shown in accordion format with all but first tab opened:

[image: accordion view]

However, the arrow keys don't trigger a `display: block;` instead of `display: none;` .

Here is the code loading the information in tabs and hopefully soon for tablet and smartphones in an accordion format:

```
<div class="demo tabs">

        <div id="tabs11" class="tabsaccordion">
            <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                <li id="tab-title-overview"><a href="#tabs-1">OVERVIEW</a></li>

                <li id="tab-title-accomodation"><a href="#tabs-2">ACCOMODATION</a></li>
                <li id="tab-title-facilities"><a href="#tabs-3"><?php if(in_category('liveaboards')) echo "SHIP FACILITIES"; else echo "RESORT FACILITIES";?></a></li>
                <li id="tab-title-diving"><a href="#tabs-4">DIVING</a></li>
                <li id="tab-title-surfing"><a href="#tabs-5">SURFING</a></li>
                <li id="tab-title-activities"><a href="#tabs-6">ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                <li id="tab-title-special"><a href="#tabs-7">SPECIAL</a></li>
            </ul>
      <div class="resp-tabs-container hor_1">
              <div id="tabs-1"><?php the_content(); //echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "overview_value", true); ?></div>
              <div id="tabs-2"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Accomodation", true);    ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Resort Facilities", true); ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-4"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Diving", true);    ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-5"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Surfing", true);   ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-6"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Activities", true);    ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-7"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Special", true);   ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    </div><!-- End demo -->
```

The script loading is triggered using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      //Horizontal Tab
      jQuery('#tabs11').easyResponsiveTabs({
          type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion
          width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
          fit: true, // 100% fit in a container
          tabidentify: 'hor_1', // The tab groups identifier
          activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
              var $tab = jQuery(this);
              var $info = jQuery('#nested-tabInfo');
              var $name = jQuery('span', $info);
              $name.text($tab.text());
              $info.show();
          }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

The JavaScript is included well and the same as on Github, only the CSS for the tabs has changed somewhat and is shown [here](http://pastebin.com/S34Qd3Vn). There are no console errors. How can I debug this?

Comment: Seems that the class `resp-tab-content-active` is not added to the content dic when I trigger display clicking the arrow in the H2 box. And the Js file from the repo to trigger this has this line on it                 `$($respTabs.find('.resp-tab-content.' + options.tabidentify)[tabNum]).addClass('resp-tab-content-active').addClass(options.tabidentify).attr('style', 'display:block');` that I think is important

Comment: Was wondering if I can just unbind jQuery UI stuff for that div so the Tabs to Accordion magic works but jQuery UI does not and this for 1000px viewports.  But I am open to other jquery ui tabs to accordion solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jakecigar](https://forum.jquery.com/user/jakecigar) at jQuery Forums came up with a solution. The code is posted [here](http://home.jejaju.com/play/tabs-or-accordion/). It allow for tabs to show a a certain viewport and an accordion at another smaller viewport which is ideal for resizing from desktop to mobile.

Code here to make solution complete in this thread and for others to use as well:

**The JavaScript**

```
! function($) {
    $.fn.tabsOrAccordion = function(e, i, t) {
        return this.each(function() {
            function n(e) {
                e.matches ? r.is(".ui-accordion") && (o.active = r.accordion("option", "active"), r.accordion("destroy").children("h3").remove(), a.clone().prependTo(r), r.tabs(o)) : r.is(".ui-tabs") && (c.active = r.tabs("option", "active"), r.tabs("destroy").children("ul").remove(), r.children().each(function(e) {
                    $("<h3>", {
                        text: a.children().eq(e).text()
                    }).insertBefore(this)
                }), r.accordion(c))
            }
            var c = $.extend({}, t),
                o = $.extend({}, i),
                a = $(this).children("ul").clone(),
                r = $(this).tabs(o);
            if ("matchMedia" in window) {
                var d = matchMedia(e);
                d.addListener(n), n(d)
            }
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```

**The html**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the forum thread itself I also mention my WordPress solution.

**HTML including WordPress PHP**

```
<div class="demo tabs">


        <div id="tabs11" class="tabsaccordion">

        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">

        <li id="tab-title-overview"><a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>


        <li id="tab-title-accomodation"><a href="#tabs-2">TO</a></li>

        <li id="tab-title-facilities"><a href="#tabs-3"><?php if(in_category('live')) echo "SHIP FACILITIES"; else echo "THREE";?></a></li>

        <li id="tab-title-d"><a href="#tabs-4">FOUR</a></li>

        <li id="tab-title-s"><a href="#tabs-5">FIVE</a></li>

        <li id="tab-title-a"><a href="#tabs-6">SIX</a></li>

        <li id="tab-title-s"><a href="#tabs-7">SEVEN</a></li>

      </ul>

          <div id="tabs-1"><?php the_content(); //echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "overview_value", true); ?></div>

          <div id="tabs-2"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID", true);
      ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID 2", true);
      ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-4"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID 3", true);
      ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-5"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID 4", true);
      ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-6"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID 5", true);
      ?></div>
        <div id="tabs-7"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ID 6", true);
      ?></div>

      </div>



        </div><!-- End demo -->
```

And the init script

```
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#tabs11" ).tabsOrAccordion("(min-width: 1000px)",{},{
            heightStyle:"content",
            collapsible: true
        })
    });
```